# CSS Code for ::selected to show up CSS text decoration

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my website and I don't know how to fix it.

I set...

```
::selection {
background: #ff6f5e;
color: #fff;
}
```

And with normal text, everything is fine within Chrome. The background of the selected text appears red and the color of the font is white.

But when I select my links ( they are CCS underline) the underline disappears. I don't like this and it is also only in Chrome, not in Firefox and Safari.

Here's the URL of one of my blog posts:

https://www.smart-minded.com/en/business/unbounce-alternatives/

I already tried out...

```
::selection {
background: #ff6f5e;
color: #fff;
text-decoration-color: #333;
}
```

... but it doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like html in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Uhm.... but the pseudoselector is ::selection not ::selected......

Comment: We meed to see your HTML in the question too, Moritz; please see the links in biberman's comments for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk with how Google Chrome handles `::selection`.  As a means of trial and error I considered how you could apply a `text-decoration` value to an anchor link within `::selection` like so:

```
:any-link::selection {
  text-decoration: ...
}
```

And of course this doesn't work so I again trial and error time... why not a border?

```
:any-link::selection {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Again this doesn't work because `::selection` has a [limited number of declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) that can be applied to it. Which leads me to the simplest solution: A new background color.  Observe.

```css
::selection {
  background: #ff6f5e;
  color: white;
}
    
:any-link::selection {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>One of the most well-known landing page builders out there is <a href="https://unbounce.grsm.io/moritzbauer8085" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Unbounce</a>. While the platform does come with great features, templates, and the ability to integrate with third-party tools, it is pretty pricey. </p>
```

Because `::selection` allows us to change things like `background` and `color` you can still achieve the accessibility benefits of an anchor tag standing apart from the rest of the text.

Comment: Hey Robert, yes – this is definitely a quirk with how Google Chrome handles ::selection. However, thanks so much for the great tip. I've implemented it on my site with another color. This idea is so cool! Cheers, Moritz